# Sqlite support for openfl

Tags: sqlite, flash, haxe, openfl

I'm trying to drop in sqlite support for saving the score and some flags. I need to open the db if it exists, then init game values based on db. If the db does not exist, I need to create/init it. The code below compiles but crashes for unknown reason.

```
    package mygame;

     <snip imports>

    import sys.db.Types;

    class ScoreDB extends sys.db.Object {
        public var id : SId;
        public var dbscore1 : SInt;
        public var dbsound  : SInt;
        public var dbscore2 : SInt;
    }

    class mygame extends Sprite {

            <snip var defines>

      public function new () {

             // start sqlite code
             sys.db.Manager.initialize();


     // db does exist
    //  then read values 
            //  currentScore = score1.dbscore1;
        //  doSound = score1.dbsound;
        //  doScore = score1.dbscore2;

    // db does not exist:

    var cnx = sys.db.Sqlite.open("mybase.db");
        sys.db.Manager.cnx = cnx;
    sys.db.TableCreate.create(ScoreDB.manager);

    var score1 = new ScoreDB();
        score1.id = 0;
    score1.dbscore1 = 0;
        score1.dbsound  = 0;
        score1.dbscore2 = 0;
    score1.insert();

            currentScore = 0;
        doSound = 0;
        doScore = 0;


        cnx.close();

        // end sqlite code

     super ();
     initialize ();
         construct ();
     newGame ();


 }
```

Comment: have you tried to run it in debug mode to get some error message (if it's android i had some luck running the openfl-created project in eclipse and using its catlog)?
Also,what target are you testing?

Comment: It's android debug targeted.  I did a logcat but saw nothing useful. I don't use eclipse or any gui, vi and console only due to vision issues.

Comment: It might be to do with Android (or iOS) having a locked down environment, and only certain folders have write access.  If SQLite tries to write to a locked folder, it will cause an error I guess. I'm not sure what the best way to get a path to a writeable folder in OpenFL is, but I think that would be the best thing to investigate next.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just solved the same issue.

The problem is that the app is essentially a .zip file and cannot be edited. You need to create (and later access) the DB in the app storage directory.

To access the directory use following code:

```
private static var localStoragePath:String = openfl.utils.SystemPath.applicationStorageDirectory;
```

There is a known bug that the IDE's don't show the SystemPath class, but don't mind it, it will compile without problem.
Later, with your common tools you can read and write the directory, create new folders etc.

Here's a quick test, to make sure it works and doesn't crash:

```
// creating a test folder
sys.FileSystem.createDirectory(openfl.utils.SystemPath.applicationStorageDirectory + "/testFolder");

var form:TextFormat = new TextFormat(null, 22, 0xFFFFFF);

// getting contents of the storage dir  
var arr = sys.FileSystem.readDirectory(openfl.utils.SystemPath.applicationStorageDirectory);

var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.defaultTextFormat = form;
tf.width = Lib.current.stage.stageWidth;
tf.height = Lib.current.stage.stageHeight;
tf.multiline = true;
tf.wordWrap = true;
tf.text = arr.toString();

addChild(tf);
```

as you'll see, the newly created folder is there. You can delete the line that creates the folder and you'll see it's safe.

Oh, an don't forget to add Android permissions in the XML file:

```
<android permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: My program still closes as soon as it hits the first sqlite statement. I tried pointing the sqlite into a custom directory, but no joy. Directory is created, but file creation for sqlite fails.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no sqlite definitions in openfl. And the ones you use are just normal cpp target definition. I suppose the problem is they don't work on android. Even more: I'm quite sure the api definitions are ok, but it tries to load dll with a wrong name, which probably kills your app without even letting out an error. Try to look into implementation(it is short and easy to understand) and change the dll name.